# An English equivalent to the Spanish phrase «Me pasó a un amigo»?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage, translation

In Spanish we sometimes say something like «Me pasó a un amigo». For example, you could be telling someone to be careful when doing something because otherwise something bad and possibly embarrassing could happen and say «Me pasó a un amigo». This is a play on words: we have the sentence «Le pasó a un amigo», which translates very directly as «It happened to a friend», but we change the «Le» to a «Me» which turns the sentence ungramatical but suggests the idea that one is trying to hide that actually it happened to us. In Spanish *to happen* can take an indirect object directly (in English you need the proposition *to*: it happened to me), and we are using the «wrong» pronoun for comedic effect. In «Me pasó a un amigo» there are two different indirect objects, the *me* and the *a un amigo*, and that is what makes the sentence incorrect, understandable, and funny.

Can one say something with a similar effect in English?

Comment: Are you asking whether English has a saying with a similar meaning (as alphabet answered below) or whether English also has verbs that can take multiple indirect objects?

Comment: The title has been edited from «an English version» to «an English equivalent», but the two things are not, hm, equivalent — the current, hm, version is asking for much more, unreasonably much more.

Comment: The broadening allows for answers, Mariano. It's highly unlikely that an idiomatic or even grammatical paraphrase or near-paraphrase of the transliterated "I happened to a friend" exists.

Comment: My friend am sure being equivalent to something is a more stringent requirement than being a version of it.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "asking for a friend" can be used in a similar (joking) way in English. It implies that someone is really asking a question on their own behalf while *pretending* to be asking on behalf of somebody else.

Of course, this applies to questions, rather than warnings, but it's a roughly similar construction.

[TFD gives this definition with two examples:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/asking+for+a+friend)

> **asking for a friend**
>
> A phrase used humorously when one is really asking about something (usually something embarrassing) for oneself.
>
> *Hey, are those unicorn decorations inappropriate for a 32-year-old's upcoming birthday? Asking for a friend.*
>
> *Do we really have to shower every day? Asking for a friend, obviously.*

Comment: Good tangential thinking. Paul set a precedent with "I know a man who ...."